# Convert Excel file to Json respecting a specific format using Python

Tags: python, json, excel

I would like to convert the following sheet of an excel file containing coordinates into a json file that looks exactly like the one below. I need it to be that way in order to run a clustering algorithm.

Thanks

[image]

```html
{ "X" : [[1.32, 2.23], [2.01, 2.223], [4.196, 4.04], [4.09, 3.96], [2.01, 3.01],
              [8.01, 7.01], [8.01, 8.01], [1.01, 8.01], [1.01, 1.10], [0.10, 7.81], [0.10, 7.91],
              [0.1, 7.91], [0.01, 7.8], [0.1, 7.8], [6.875, 1.43], [6.99, 1.54], [6.71, 1.37],
              [7.98, 1.1], [7.33, 1.53], [6.43, 1.3], [6.99, 1.3], [4.11, 4.11]]
}
```

Comment: What is your attempt code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution and adapt it to your dataframe:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2],
                   [3, 4],
                   [5, 6],
                   [7, 8]
                   ],
                  columns=['x', 'y'])

# Convert DataFrame to JSON
data = df.to_json(orient='values')
output = '{ "X" :'+data+'}'
print(output)
```

Output:

```
{ "X" :[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]}
```